# React navigate conditionally with useSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I check whether there is any query string with route v6? I would like to achieve the same result as below ternary condition with `searchParams`

```
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split("=")[1] : "/";
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect);
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect]);
```

For instance, if there is any query string like the below it should redirect to  `shipping` if not it should redirect to `/`

```
  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/login?redirect=shipping')
  }
```

I tried something below but it did not work for me.

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams(); 
const redirect = searchParams ? searchParams.get('redirect') : "/";
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header />
  <Container>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/shipping" element={<ShippingScreen />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
    </Routes>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <Footer />
  </Container>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a specific path, or are you trying to navigate to the same path with a specific `redirect` query parameter? Is the navigation contingent on there being *any* query search params, or does any specific query param need to exist? Please clarify what the issue is, i.e. what isn't working, and the exact behavior you are trying to capture.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, for example in when I submit the checkout button,it should navigate me to the `/login?redirect=shipping` which is login page if user not logged in.. After login it needs to navigate me to `shipping` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation you have appears is *mostly* correct.

```
const redirect = searchParams ? searchParams.get('redirect') : "/";
```

The `searchParams` will *always* be a defined `URLSearchParams` object, so the `redirect` variable is assigned the result value of `searchParams.get('redirect')` which will either be the *actual* `"redirect"` query parameter value, i.e. `"shipping"` or `null` if it doesn't exist. Something like `const redirect = searchParams.get('redirect') ? searchParams.get('redirect') : "/";` would be a bit more correct.

An additional issue I see is one of relative vs absolute path navigation. With a URL path/queryString like `"/login?redirect=shipping"` the `redirect` value is `"shipping"` and the `navigate` function will try to navigate relative to the current matched path.

You could prepend a leading `"/"` character to the path to make it an absolute path.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

const redirect = searchParams.get('redirect');

...

navigate(`/${redirect ?? ""}`, { replace: true });
```

It would of course be better to pass the target path formatted as you expect to begin with, i.e. make the URL path/search something more like `"/login?redirect=/shipping"`.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

const redirect = searchParams.get('redirect');

...

navigate(redirect ?? "/", { replace: true });
```